# Pyinstaller doesn`t see imports in settings.py

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller

When i create .exe `pyinstaller --onefile main.py --window` and open it i get an error `No module named 'glcontext'`

[image: like this]

I believe this is because most of my modules are in settings.py

[image]

I tried `--path` and `--hidden-import settings.py` but nothing helped.
Still new with pyinstaller and really don`t know what to do.

EDIT: Okey, i solved it just adding `--hidden-import glcontext` ...